# Long-running Golang program and resources (file handles, tcp connections, etc)

Tags: php, file, networking, go

I'm coming from a PHP background and I'm a bit confused about how to safely use resources with Golang. My main concern is, in a web context, with PHP, scripts are usually short-lived (HTTP request / response lifetime), but with Golang they're supposed to run forever (because the Golang program acts as a web server and a web application at the same time).

So, when it comes to deal with database connections, log files, I often see that they should be opened once and not for each request, which makes sense. However how stable is it to do this?

For example, if I open a database connection, how can I be sure it won't break at some point? (if the database decides to kill it for some reason, or if my machine looses internet access, would the connection become valid again when I gain internet access later on?) Same for log files, with PHP it's not a problem for a sysadmin to setup log rotation, however in Golang it would break the file handle I think (if the program doesn't know about this)?

I'd really like to work the Golang way and not open/close those resources for each request but I'm not sure what is the "safe" way to do this, are there any recommendations for this? Or is there built-in features for those concerns?

Comment: Database access is usually done through a connection pool, which will connect/reconnect as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Go, there are built-in packages that will handle both log files and databases in a Go idiomatic way.

They are:

- database/sql: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql
- log: https://golang.org/pkg/log

In Go, as with any language where long running daemon's can be created, error checking and error handling will be important.